# Is it ok to have @Resource injection in abstract super class of an EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, inheritance, ejb, code-injection, wildfly-8

We have multiple EJBs inheriting from an abstract super class.
In this abstract super class we inject a resource through the @Resource annotation.
Everything works fine but in Jboss Wildfly (8.2.0) it gives us warnings in the logs on startup:

> @Resource injection of type xxx is not supported for non-ejb
>   components.

So I wanted to know if it is completely safe to have the @Resource annotation in the abstract class ?

Note that in this abstract class we have also @EJB injections for which we have no warnings at all.

Answer (score -2):

My guess would be that you are getting this warning since you cannot guarantee that only EJB-classes are inheriting from your abstract super class.

To avoid future problems you could write a unit test which iterates through all classes extending the base class (by reflection) and checks for the *@Stateless*/*@Stateful*-annotation.
This test would have to be included in all projects which depend on you base class-project.